# Angular Material: Button style issue

Tags: angular, button, angular-material

I am trying to use the buttons provided by Material but I can not make it work. Although it works halfway, when clicking it does not behave as it should, I probably need to import some module but in principle everything should go well.

The same happens if I try to use the icon buttons.

[image: Demo]

My Module class:

```
import { WebsocketService } from './services/websocket.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCardModule, MatExpansionModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AdminService } from './services/admin.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AdminService,
    WebsocketService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My HTML:

```
...
<div class="pl-4 pr-4">

  <button mat-button>Actualizar</button>

  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>
...
```

Comment: Check if you have any other css conflicting with the material one.

Comment: @Justcode I have not created any style. the only css file that exists is the generated by angular-cli and is empty.

Comment: Did you follow this example?https://stackblitz.com/angular/pyvlxeodgrd?file=main.ts

Comment: @Justcode I installed bootstrap 4.0 and its dependencies .. could it be the problem?

Comment: You need to inspect and check using click event handler, that what css are applying.

Comment: @Justcode mh, I do not know if this helps. https://imgur.com/a/lfRsB What would be the best way to prove it?

Comment: check that `button:focus` outline is 5px auto remove it and try again.

Comment: @Justcode I disable bootstrap and verify that the blue border is generated by bootstrap. But it still does not show the animation when press the button.

Comment: @Justcode i forget to include a theme of angular to the main style.css, that's why it did not show the animations of the button. I like the blue border that adds bootstrap. Thank you!